# Vue: Refactoring a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following computed property that works as expected.  I want it to return true if any of the 3 data properties are empty strings and want it return true if any of the strings are "n/a":

```
             appNamesInvalid() {
                if (!this.preferredAppName1 || !this.preferredAppName2 || !this.preferredAppName3) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (this.preferredAppName1.toLowerCase().includes('n/a') || this.preferredAppName2.toLowerCase().includes('n/a') || this.preferredAppName3.toLowerCase().includes('n/a')) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
```

I had originally tried to do this but this wasn't working as expected and I can't tell why:

```
   appNamesInvalid() {
        let appNames = [this.preferredAppName1, this.preferredAppName2, this.preferredAppName3];
        appNames.forEach(appName => {
            if (appName == "" || appName.toLowerCase().includes("n/a")) { 
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
```

Is there a cleaner way of refactoring the working code in the first block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return a boolean based on your specific criteria:

```
appNamesInvalid() {
  let appNames = [this.preferredAppName1, this.preferredAppName2, this.preferredAppName3];
  return appNames.some(appName => {
      return appName === "" || appName.toLowerCase().includes("n/a");
  }
},
```

That would return `true` if for any aoo either `appName === ""` or `appName.toLowerCase().includes("n/a")` is true.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Check the return value for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)